# List Categories (wp_list_categories) stopped working after wordpress Update

Tags: wordpress, categories, wp-list-categories

I updated wordpress on old website which display list of categories in sidebar.
Old Code used in sidebar.php to display list:
`<?php wp_list_categories('child_of=6&orderby=name&optioncount=0&title_li='); ?>`

Now after update, categories list not showing in sidebar, it shows "No categories" text only.

After searching wordpress codex I also tried this:

```
            $args = array(
                'child_of'  => 6,                   
                'orderby'   => 'name',
                'show_count'    => 1,
                'title_li'  => '',
                'hide_empty'    => 0
                );
            wp_list_categories($args);
```

Still showing "No categories"
When I use wp_list_categories(); it shows all categories list but not showing list when using arguments.
Also tried default theme and disable plugins but still same problem.

Comment: are you definitely sure there is a cateogory with term id = 6 containing subcats?

Comment: also, what if you use get_terms: `$terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'categories',     'parent' => 6 ) );` does it return anything? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Comment: @GrafiCode: yes code and database same that worked with old versions.

Comment: @GrafiCode: getting error : Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Comment: i think there is some problem with parent child relationship system, when i open categories page it shows total 73 categories and only parent categories are listed there. So i have to edit and update all one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it.
There was some categories relationship issue in database.

If anyone having the same issue, here is the solution.

You have  to Edit and save the categories again.
if categories not visible in the admin panel then
use the link to edit and save the categories.

```
https://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=1&post_type=post
```

change the tag_id 1, 2 and so on for all the categories and update, with this wordpress will re build/update the relationship in database.

Thanks.